# Finding a tree decomposition of a graph in Python

Tags: python, algorithm, tree, graph-theory, decomposition

I need an algorithm that can find a tree decomposition given a graph in Python, the graphs will be small so it doesn't need to be very efficient. I have looked around but cannot find much on this at all. Anyone know of a package that can do this or some sudo code I could use to make my own?

Comment: sounds related to [CSTheory: Program for computing Tree decomposition of a graph](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/6034/program-for-computing-tree-decomposition-of-a-graph)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at networkx? See: https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms/approximation.html